# Nonblocking io using BinaryWriter to write to usblp0

Tags: c#, binarywriter

I'm doing a program in c# (mono) to print to a fiscal printer (escpos) and it works okay. The problem is that when I print, the program hangs until the buffer I have is cleared. So, as you imagine if I print a couple of images it gets bigger and so it hangs for a while. This is not desirable. I have tested in 2 ways

**One way**:

```
BinaryWriter outBuffer;
this.outBuffer = new BinaryWriter(new  FileStream (this.portName,System.IO.FileMode.Open));
.... apend bytes to buffer...
IAsyncResult asyncResult = null; 
asyncResult = outBuffer.BaseStream.BeginWrite(buffer,offset,count,null,null);
asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(100);
outBuffer.BaseStream.EndWrite(asyncResult); // Last step to the 'write'.
if (!asyncResult.IsCompleted) // Make sure the write really completed.
{
throw new IOException("Writte to printer failed.");             
}
```

**second Way**:

```
BinaryWriter outBuffer;
this.outBuffer = new BinaryWriter(new  FileStream (this.portName,System.IO.FileMode.Open));
.... apend bytes to buffer...
outBuffer.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

and neither method is allowing the program to continue the execution. Example: if it starts to print and paper is out it will hang until the printer resumes printing which is not the right way.

Thanks in advance for your time and patience.

Comment: You must provide callback to `BeginWrite` method, which will be invoked on write completion.

Comment: Why use a `BinaryWriter` when you're writing directly to the underlying stream? Why not just `f = new FileStream(...)` and then call `f.BeginWrite`?

Comment: Jim Mischel, what will i earn with that? Im doing in method one a similar procedure. outBuffer.BaseStream.BeginWrite

Comment: The question isn't what you gain from using the `FileStream` directly. The question is what you gain by using `BinaryWriter`. Why create a `FileStream` *and* a `BinaryWriter` when `FileStream` by itself works just fine?

Comment: Jim, i need to write binary data, i miss understood your last answer. So i use a binary writter on top of a filestream so i can write binary data to the printer paralel port. Dont know any other good method for it, if u have please share!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're making the program wait for the write to complete. If you want it to happen asynchronously, then you need to provide a callback method that will be called when the write is done. For example:

```
asyncResult = outBuffer.BaseStream.BeginWrite(buffer,offset,count,WriteCallback,outBuffer);

private void WriteCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var buff = (BinaryWriter)ar.AsyncState;
    // following will throw an exception if there was an error
    var bytesWritten = buff.BaseStream.EndWrite(ar);

    // do whatever you need to do to notify the program that the write completed.
}
```

That's one way to do it. You should read up on the [Asynchronous Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx) for other options, and pick the one that best suits your needs.

You can also use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), which might be a better fit.

Comment: Iv viewed the source code of the mono and i see that "Timeouts are not supported on this stream." wich means i wont have any method good enougth to alert when printer was opened or anything else.

Comment: @CésarAraújo: Then you probably want to use `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` to register a wait and a timeout, and then call `Stream.WriteAsync` with a cancellation token to do the write. If the wait signals a timeout, then you can cancel the printing operation. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137799.aspx. Or perhaps the `Task` has some timeout capability. I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Iv found a solution. Starting a thread and doing a timeout in the thread seems todo the job. Thanks for all the help.